# Ambiguous JOIN variable - in initial FROM... really?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, syntax

EDIT OK so the main problem here was initial `column1 FROM table1` with the join. Even that `column1` has to be fully defined as `table1.column1` even tho it is next to the `FROM` which seems at best odd to me. But I guess this is a newb error and I hope other newbs will find this useful.
//========================================================================

Have used simple joins before without problems. I thought the `table.column` format was unambiguous.

Warning is:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'transmissionProgramID' 
in field list is ambiguous'
```

The SQL is:

```
SELECT transmissionProgramID FROM transmissionProgramOwner 
JOIN transmissionProgram on transmissionProgram.transmissionProgramID 
= transmissionProgramOwner.transmissionProgramID WHERE  
ownerType = '$ownerType' AND ownerID = '$ownerID'  ORDER BY startDate
```

The two table `transmissionProgramOwner` and `transmissionProgram` both have fields called `transmissionProgramID`. I just cannot see how the `table.column` leaves anything ambiguous.

Sure it is something simple but I cannot see it. And I apologize for the long variable names but helps me keep things clear.

Additional info: Both `transmissionProgramID` are set to unique in both tables. I have tried every flaovor of `JOIN` but I think a simple join is allowed which just returns all records that match... In any case have tried every type of join just to make sure.

Comment: Ambiguity is in `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friend try this

```
SELECT t1.transmissionProgramID FROM transmissionProgramOwner t1
JOIN transmissionProgram t2 on  t2.transmissionProgramID
= t1.transmissionProgramID WHERE  
t1.ownerType = '$ownerType' AND t1.ownerID = '$ownerID'  ORDER BY t1.startDate;
```

Comment: Excellent thanks. Do NOT understand why i have to use aliasing but it works. All v odd I think. I tried to edit your answer. There are two tiny things there is an extra " ' " just before the WHERE and the startDate is in t2 but you have to edit 10 characters and felt bad about that. Once again thanks for the help. Most useful.

Comment: Thanks dearr for nice comment. i removed extra " ' " from code. Happy to help always

Comment: the "extra aliasing" was to resolve the amigbuity. BOTH tables have the column named `transmissionProgramID` so if you `select transmissionProgramID` WHICH ONE do you want? i.e. because you had not specified the table, it is ambiguous as there is more then one of them. You could use the whole table names **instead**, those aliases just help to make your code shorter.

Comment: Thanks but as you say the aliasing is not necessary. The error was not to use `t1.c1` in the `SELECT` at the start. This to me is dreadful syntax design. (Not sure if this is all SQL or just MySQL.) The first part of a`JOIN` is a standard, "well formed", `SELECT`. Get x from y is completely unambiguous. That this tripped me up sort of proves that this is syntactically **illogical**. To design a language where the addition of another clause unnecessarily changes the already existing clause syntax is daft in the extreme. But heh, MySQL is lovely so I will bend to their collective insanity!

Answer (score 0):

change to

> SELECT transmissionProgram.transmissionProgramID FROM
>   transmissionProgramOwner  JOIN transmissionProgram on 
>   'transmissionProgram.transmissionProgramID' 
>   = 'transmissionProgramOwner.transmissionProgramID' WHERE   ownerType = '$ownerType' AND ownerID = '$ownerID'  ORDER BY startDate

Comment: Thanks yep got that. Really do not understand how the `FROM` can be ambiguous but I don't write the spec for SQL. Also this does not work because in my desperation I was throwing around single quotes around and tried them in the ON expression and it screws that up (my bad and thanks for the input).